# How to do a redirect without the original referrer showing?

Tags: javascript, http, redirect

I need to do redirect my site visitors to a third party site, without the original referrer showing as the urls disclose private information.

Is there a way to instruct a browser redirection without a referrer being sent to the destination site? E.g. using javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Your answer has been posted below. But may I suggest **extreme caution** toward the idea of having persistent, private information in URLs. It is a very bad thing to do. There are other ways that information could be stolen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a quick workaround, you could redirect them to a special URL owned by you which exclusively redirects to the target URL (or one provided as a query parameter, for example).  This way the private information would be lost in the extra hop.

Comment: when I do this with e.g. a tinyurl redirection, the original referrer still shows when loading the final destination page.

Comment: Right, you'll have to setup your own HTTP request handler which simply responds "302 Found" with a Location header as your redirect URL and ideally overwriting the Referer header, in case your webserver or container copies that header automatically for 302 responses.

Answer (score 6):

With JavaScript: You can create a link with referrer-suppressing attributes and then simulate a click on it.

```js
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.referrerPolicy = "no-referrer";
link.rel = "noreferrer";

link.href = "https://example.org/";
link.click();
```

Alternatively, in a pure HTTP redirect, you can send the [**`Referrer-Policy: no-referrer`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) header along with the redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.someplace.com">
```

Comment: this still results with the original url sent as the referrer

Answer (score 0):

You will need to redirect through another page.  You can do a POST to your own page which then does a redirect to the destination.  This will show only your intermediate page as the referrer.

There is not a way to do this with just javascript.

Answer (score -5):

Try redirect with curl for example.